# sizectl in concurrentHashMap in java8

Tags: java, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

Since I am reading the source code of the concurrentHashMap in java8, I am a little confused about the `sizeCtl` variable, it says

> When negative, the table is being initialized or resized: -1 for initialization, else -(1 + the number of active resizing threads)

But in the source code, it will use `U.compareAndSetInt(this, SIZECTL, sc, sc + 1)` when trying to resize the `ConcurrentHashMap` and use `U.compareAndSetInt(this, SIZECTL, sc = sizeCtl, sc - 1)` after finishing the operation.

These operations confuse me, for example, if there is 2 thread resize the map at the same time, then the `sizeCtl` is is `-3`, however, when a new thread try to help resize, the `sizeCtl` should be `-4` according to the description of the comment above, but it seems to be `-2` according to the code `U.compareAndSetInt(this, SIZECTL, sc, sc + 1)`.

```
final Node<K,V>[] helpTransfer(Node<K,V>[] tab, Node<K,V> f) {
    Node<K,V>[] nextTab; int sc;
    if (tab != null && (f instanceof ForwardingNode) &&
        (nextTab = ((ForwardingNode<K,V>)f).nextTable) != null) {
        int rs = resizeStamp(tab.length);
        while (nextTab == nextTable && table == tab &&
               (sc = sizeCtl) < 0) {
            if ((sc >>> RESIZE_STAMP_SHIFT) != rs || sc == rs + 1 ||
                sc == rs + MAX_RESIZERS || transferIndex <= 0)
                break;
            if (U.compareAndSwapInt(this, SIZECTL, sc, sc + 1)) {
                transfer(tab, nextTab);
                break;
            }
        }
        return nextTab;
    }
    return table;
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting question. Perhaps, you should add a link to the source of `ConcurrentHashMap` and include the relevant snippets in the question itself. This will make your question easier to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it says wrong.

> When negative, the table is being initialized or resized: -1 for initialization, else -(1 + the number of active resizing threads)

Since the first thread which is into the function `transfer` sets `sizeCtl` to `(resizeStamp(tab.length) << RESIZE_STAMP_SHIFT) + 2`. It's a negative which's absolve value is very big. This sizeCtl increments 1 when each thread enters the function, and then subtracts 1 before each thread goes out of the function.

```
while (s >= (long)(sc = sizeCtl) && (tab = table) != null &&
               (n = tab.length) < MAXIMUM_CAPACITY) {
            int rs = resizeStamp(n);
            if (sc < 0) {
                if ((sc >>> RESIZE_STAMP_SHIFT) != rs || sc == rs + 1 ||
                    sc == rs + MAX_RESIZERS || (nt = nextTable) == null ||
                    transferIndex <= 0)
                    break;
                if (U.compareAndSwapInt(this, SIZECTL, sc, sc + 1))
                    transfer(tab, nt);
            }
            else if (U.compareAndSwapInt(this, SIZECTL, sc,
                                         (rs << RESIZE_STAMP_SHIFT) + 2))
                transfer(tab, null);
            s = sumCount();
        }
```

These are my thoughts, but I'm not sure.